# How to use MainWindow as ShellViewModel View?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I understand that by default CM will look for ShellView in Views folder to use as ShellViewModel View but I want to use the MainWindow instead... can this be done and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### How it Works

CM uses a set of [**View/ViewModel Naming Conventions**](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=View/ViewModel%20Naming%20Conventions), generally speaking, if you have a ViewModel named `FooViewModel` CM will attempt to locate a type with a similar name of `FooView` or `FooPage`.

### What if you *really* want "MainWindow" and "ShellViewModel"?

If you just wanted to use an existing "MainWindow" with an existing 'root viewmodel' then consider subclassing `Bootstrapper<TRootModel>` and override `OnStartUp`. This is a prescribed method, but can seem daunting.

*(I have not tested this code.)*

```
    protected override void OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        var rootModel = IoC.Get<TRootModel>();
        var rootView = new MainWindow();
        ViewModelBinder.Bind(rootModel, rootView, this);
        rootView.Show();
    }
```

The above method, of course, would only apply to the initial view for the root view model shown during start-up. Future attempts to display a view for `ShellViewModel` may work, or they may result in errors, I am not certain.

### Extending Conventions

There are a few ways to customize the convention itself. The most flexible and direct method is to intercept/hook `Caliburn.Micro.ViewLocator.LocateForModelType`, this allows you to modify the behavior/strategy applied during view location.

```
    private static void CustomViewLocatorStrategy()
    {
        // store original implementation so we can fall back to it as necessary
        var originalLocatorStrategy = Caliburn.Micro.ViewLocator.LocateForModelType;

        // intercept ViewLocator.LocateForModelType requests and apply custom mappings
        Caliburn.Micro.ViewLocator.LocateForModelType = (modelType, displayLocation, context) =>
        {
            // implement your custom logic
            if (modelType == typeof(ShellViewModel))
            {
                return new MainWindow();
            }
            // fall back on original locator
            return originalLocatorStrategy(modelType, displayLocation, context);
        };
    }
```

The above can be called from inside a `Bootstrapper<TRootModel>.Configure` override:

```
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        CustomViewLocatorStrategy();
        base.Configure();
    }
```

This method is more likely to play well with CM (in terms of any view caching, namely.) However, it still breaks conventions, and it's still a fair amount of code.

### Registering Additional Suffixes?

One thing I want to point out, but have not had a chance to play with, is `ViewLocator.RegisterViewSuffix` implementation. I believe if you executed `ViewLocator.RegisterViewSuffix(@"Window")` then you could rely on CM to map `MainViewModel` to `MainWindow`.

This would allow for more expressive suffixes (such as Window, Dialog, Form, or others you may want to use.) Personally I dislike the use of 'View' as a suffix, I believe it's too generic (after all, they are all Views.)

Comment: It looks like <TRootView> generic version of Bootstrapper is no more. I hate it when people try to get fancy without updating the docs

Comment: Documentation (or lack thereof) is a huge problem with Caliburn. Most of the time you're better of reading the code, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Caliburn.Micro doesn't look for ShellView by default, this is how things work. Let's say you have a bootstrapper defined like this:

```
class MyBootsrtapper : Bootstrapper<MyViewModel> { }
```

Then CM (Caliburn.Micro) will look for a view named MyView. So yes you can use MainWindow instead as long as your view model name is MainWindowViewModel.
I have answered the other question you have asked and it seems you don't fully comprehend CM so i **really really advise** you to [**Start Here**](http://devlicio.us/blogs/rob_eisenberg/archive/2010/07/04/mvvm-study-segue-introducing-caliburn-micro.aspx) and you can always check the projects [**Documentation**](https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/documentation) on codeplex because it contains all updated information and documentation.

**Edit:**

> Caliburn.Micro uses a simple naming convention to locate Views for
>   ViewModels. Essentially, it takes the FullName and removes “Model”
>   from it. So, given MyApp.ViewModels.MyViewModel, it would look for
>   MyApp.Views.MyView.

Taken from [official documentation here](https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Basic%20Configuration,%20Actions%20and%20Conventions&referringTitle=Documentation).

Comment: Thanks for your replay, if I fully comprehended CM I wouldn't be asking CM questions... would I? That being said ShellView and ShellViewModel was just an example, I do comprehend that if VM was named SomeNameViewModel CM would be looking for SomeNameView and your suggestion would require moving the MainWindow into the Views folder because CM would not find it in the root would it?

Comment: @DeanKuga i am sorry if said anything wrong, i didn't mean that. I have edited my answer, please check the edit.