# How to use my own MainWindow with Caliburn.Micro?

Tags: caliburn.micro

A similar question is [asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17372297/how-to-use-mainwindow-as-shellviewmodel-view) but `CM` has changed and the solution provided to that question is not supported anymore.

The solution to the question mentioned above was to write your own `Bootstrapper<TRootView>` derived class. But the generic version of `Bootstrapper` is not there in the latest version.

What is the alternate ?

I have the following folder hierarchy in project

```
 Project
   |-Modules
      |-MainWindow
         |-ViewModels
             |- MainWindowViewModel
         |-Views
             |- MainWindow.xaml
```

Here is my OnStartup override

```
protected override void OnStartup(object sender, System.Windows.StartupEventArgs e)
{
    DisplayRootViewFor<MainWindowViewModel>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your bootstrapper now inherits BootstrapperBase, then you use

`DisplayRootViewFor<T>`

then depending on your flavor of view-first / viewmodel-first development.  Usually done in the OnStartUp override.

Edit:
Glad you figured it out...

Comment: Added more details to the question

Comment: ok so adding the using namespace to the bootstrapper for your setup is out of the question?

Comment: I figured what is wrong. I had to rename MainWindow to MainWindowView. Do you wanna change your answer ?

Comment: If you figured it out, not sure what else I can assist with.